# How can access directive from others in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i have a problem with directive access from another and code is below

```
app.module('myApp', [])
.directive('vikiQues', ['$http', '$compile', function($http, $compile){
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : true,
    controller : [
        function (){
        }
    ],
    link : function(scope, iElement, iAttrs){
        $http.get('getOutside/1')
            .then(function(data){
                iElement.html($compile($(data.data))(scope));
                /*scope.addThere.find('div.please-wait').remove();
                scope.questionList.push({
                    text : '',
                    options : []
                });*/
            });
    }
};
}]).directive('vikiOption', ['$http', '$compile', function ($http, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope : true,
    require : '^vikiQues',
    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, vikiQuesCtrl) {
        $http.get('getInside/1')
            .then(function(data){
                var _ = $(data.data);
                scope._opt = false;
                iElement.html($compile(_)(scope));
                if ( scope.$parent.questionList[scope.$parent.totalQuestionCount-1].options.length > 2)
                    _opt = true;
                scope.now = {
                    id : scope.$parent.questionList[scope.$parent.totalQuestionCount-1].options.length,
                    char : '',
                    text : '',
                    image : '',
                    removeable : scope._opt,
                };
                ques.now.options.push(scope.now);
            });
    }
};
```

}]);

i got this error everytime : angular.min.js:117 Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$compile/ctreq?p0=vikiQues&p1=vikiOption

what is wrong in there ?

html code:
    
            
                 0">
                    
                        
                    
                    
                        
                    
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                        
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                
        
        
            
        
        
            
        
        
        
            
        
    
        
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
viki-ques and viki-option are templates which come from php.
if i remove
iElement.html($compile($(data.data))(scope));
code, i can't get error. i think i have mistake there . ithink $compile or scope provide this error . ( help )

Comment: <viki-ques>
    <viki-option></viki-option>
</viki-ques>

i get an question template from php and set html to viki-ques element and get some option from php again and set html to viki-option ... 

is  it enough?

Comment: Not enough info to help. Create demo with the issue, then it's easy to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
require : 'vikiQues',
```

or You should change

```
controller : [
        function (){
        }
    ],
```

to:

```
controller : function (){},
```

Comment: try the second one

Comment: You are just trying to guess? The first one doesn't make sense with HTML structure OP has. The second one is just minification unsafe version of the first one, so can't change anything. OP didn't add enough details to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

according to [directives documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) (serach for *Creating Directives that Communicate*) you need to require your parent directive like this:

```
.directive('vikiOption', function(){
  return {
      restrict : 'E',
      require: '^vikiQues',
      template: '<li>my items</li>',
      //templateUrl: 'url to html file with html from previous line',
      scope : true,
      link : function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){ console.log(ctrl); }
  };
});
```

character `^` means angular will try to find required directive upper in markup  hierarchy

and you need to have a controller in your `vikiQues` directive, declare it like this

```
.directive('vikiQues', function(){
  return {
      restrict : 'E',
      transclude: true, //attention here!!
      scope : true,
      template: '<ul ng-transclude>item x</ul>', //and here, now you can instert vikiOption inside
      controller : function (){ //pay attention no brackets
        this.myProp = 'foo';  
      }
  };
});
```

and your markup ot use this:

```
<viki-queues>
  <viki-option>can use ng-repet for viki-option<viki-option/>
  <viki-option>to display a list of them<viki-option/>
</viki-queues>
```

P.S. templateUrl is more handy since you can keep your markup in separate file or get it from template engine like asp.net or other or just server them as common static html files

P.P.S hope this helps

Comment: So you just repeated what OP already has: both `^vikiQues` and controller are there.

Comment: i've never seen controller declaration in array, so it's not the same

Comment: i saw this declaration everywhere so i use it but not

Comment: i don't see template/templateUrl in your directives! try to simplify your conditions, declare templateUrl and just serve templates, don't use $compile

Comment: Well then I can tell you that `[ function () {} ]` is the bacicaly same as `function () {}`. So `function () {}` didn't work, then your version is also useless.

Comment: @Denis how can use template ... i use $http.get function with " index.php?route=quiz/create/vikiQuestion " url . if i write this templateUrl i get error